# Font Awesome Pro Icons not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, font-awesome

I have font awesome pro installed in my project but the pro icons are not showing up in my project. The free version works fine.

```html
import React from 'react';
import ProfileCard from './ProfileCard';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCalendar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const MeetingStart = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mt-2 p-4">
      <h4>Group Name</h4>

      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <div className="meeting-date row mr-2">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendar} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-regular fa-memo" />
          <p>{new Date().toDateString().slice(0, 10)}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  );
};

export default MeetingStart;
```

In this example faCalendar works but fa-memo doesn't. I tried re-installing the packages but that didn't seem to change anything.

Link to docs:
https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/

Comment: `For Pro icons, you'll first need to set up access with your secret Font Awesome npm token and global or per-project access.` Did you? You have to demonstrate that you paid for the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already checked to have all the dependencies installed for the pro version?

```
FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN=FONT-AWESOME-PACKAGE-TOKEN npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro

npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest
```

Comment: Checked and re-installed, still no change

Comment: and did you set the fontawsome token?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/packages#configure-access

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an invalid token for font-awesome pro